# The import javax.jws cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a). I am trying to create a web service application. but when i am trying to create an interface class with **import javax.jws.WebService;** i am getting error as "The import javax.jws cannot be resolved"

I am using tomcat 8.5 and i have added the library in java build path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i replaced jdk 9 with jdk 8 in program files it worked.